# odp.net freezing on executenonquery while calling oracle storproc with xmltype input parameter

Tags: asp.net, odp.net

I have an issue in calling oracle stored procedures(oracle xmltype as input parameter) in ASP.NET 2.0 using ODP.NET (Oracle.DataAccess assembly version 9.2.0.700).the web page freezes during processing on executenonquery.

Executenonquery is not firing any command on database. i have implemented some tracing logic and found that no request is made to database procedure and web page is freezes.

Comment: does it work with store procedures with other input types? is it the connection open successfully? where did you put tracing logic?

Comment: Are you sure the stored procedure you are calling does return?

Comment: Can you tried ? any solution about it ??

Answer (score 3):

I just had an issue calling a stored procedure using inputoutput parameters that was freezing on ExecuteNonQuery. My code looked correct. I had Oracle SQL Developer opened that had some non commited transactions. I disconnected from the database. The dba killed all of my processes. I ran the same code again and it worked perfectly.